# How to draw the graph of the $\sum_{n\geq 0}1_{[0,n]}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Do you know how can I draw the graph of the following function?
$$
f=\sum_{n\geq 0}1_{[0,n]}
$$
I can see for example that the image of any point is infinity. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is not a function whose graph can be plotted: that's because it is not a function whose values are real numebrs.

Comment: You mean the image of any *non-negative* point is $\infty$; the image of any negative number is $0$. Following @Crostul's comment that only real-valued functions can be graphed, I'd regard $f$ as real-valued, meaning its domain is only the negative part of the real line. $f(x)$ is (as a real number) undefined if $x\geq0$. So the graph consists of just the negative $x$-axis.

Comment: You probably instead want to graph $$ f= \sum_{n\ge 0} \unicode{x1D7D9}_{[n,\infty)}$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor That does seem like a more sensible question, but the OP did say that "I can see for example that the image of any point is infinity" so my guess is that he meant what he wrote.

Comment: Hmm. perhaps then the OP is analysing a problem that was transcribed incorrectly. Or if the problem is of OP's own creation then fair enough @bof

Comment: The question was stated exactly as mentioned above. Thanks Andreas for your clear answer!